# Use HTML files as templates for Sencha?

Tags: javascript, mobile, sencha-touch, extjs

I am starting out with [Sencha](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/)'s mobile web app framework. It seems the interface has to be always built procedurally or with html strings. This is so unintuitive! Is there a way to put your template code in an HTML file and have Sencha use those files as templates? That way I can have a clear separation from the interface layer. Thanks for any advise or experience.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? You can write an HTML page defining the basic layout of the page, then wire everything together by supplying ids to the `renderTo` properties of the various objects. Do you have an example of something more 'intuitive'?

Comment: @NT3RP, that sounds like what I am exactly looking for!! I do not know about the renderTo options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your basic html, then 'wire' the application together. Just about every component has a key called `renderTo`. So if you had a very simple html template like this:

```
<body>
    <div id="myButton"></div>
</body>
```

You could create a button and wire it to that div with the following javascript:

```
var button = Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
    text: 'Button',
    renderTo: '#myButton'
});
```

...That being said, Sencha's frameworks expect that you design applications programmatically (that is, entirely in Javascript).

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot! I will try it out and see if it feels more intuitive. BTW, jQuery Mobile feels so natural because it expects that you design applications through HTML5 markup with classes and data-* attributes.

Answer (score 1):

You could return a template or markup from an external file using an ajax request.

The items of your panel would look something like the following:

```
items: [
  {
    id: "panel",
    html: "<p>Loading...</p>"
  }
]
```

Then you could use the ajax request to update the content of the **panel** element with the content of **template.html**:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
  url: 'template.html',        
  callback: function(options, success, response) {
    this.getComponent('panel').update(response.responseText);
  },
  scope: this
});
```

Updating your content this way is useful if your managed content is only available as markup or you haven't got round to creating a web service using json, for example.